# Copy request to different URL with .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Looking through mod_rewrite manual, I have been trying to find a way to send a copy of a request for a particular directory or site to an alternative URL, while ALSO sending the request to it's originally intended link.

So if the user requests the URL:

http://www.site.com/test/

The .htaccess located in the test directory would also send a copy of the GET/POST request to:
http://www.site.com/test/ 
-and-
http://www.different_site.com/

Any ideas on how this could be achieved?

Comment: Don't think you can do that with htaccess. If you send the request to two different places, which response gets returned to the client?

Comment: The second location would not return any information to the client, it only logs the request..

Answer (score 0):

Send the request to the second place from your first URL, parse the response and return that to the client. I cannot guarantee that I am right, but I really believe you should not be able to do that using htaccess because that would potentially introduce ambiguity in the requesting logic.

Comment: Unfortunately, due to the nature of this issue, I do not have control over the scripts in /test/ - only the .htaccess with in that directory..